# É uma boa prática importar módulos no __init__.py

Tags: python, django

Eu reparei que no Django framework os módulos são importados no **__init__**.py por conveniência.

```
"""
Django validation and HTML form handling.
"""
from django.forms.forms import *  # NOQA
```

Dessa forma isso:

```
from django.forms.forms import Form
```

Se torna isso:

```
from django.forms import Form
```

Isso deixa o código mais legível, porém atualizar o arquivo **__init__**.py em uma aplicação em constante desenvolvimento parece entediante. É uma boa prática fazer isso em algo que não seja um framework? Existe ferramentas que facilitam esse processo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você meio que matou a charada. Minha impressão também é que isso é natural em frameworks.

Componentes de frameworks podem crescer para se tornar bem complicados. Imagine como o código de formulários de Django deve ser grande! Já sabemos, porém, como lidar com códigos grandes: dividimo-los em vários arquivos.

## Por que criar vários arquivos

Considere um framework hipotético, por exemplo, que tenha vários tipos de classes que representam páginas Web. Todas herdarão de uma classe base chamada `Page`; haverá uma classe que apenas serve conteúdo estático de um arquivo, e será chamada `ResourcePage`; outra classe terá várias facilidades para JavaScript e CSS, e se chamará `RichPage`; uma terceira pode ler Markdown e gerar HTML e se chamará `MarkdownPage` etc. Se usássemos um só arquivo, teríamos uma estrutura como abaixo:

```
- framework
   - page.py
```

E `page.py` teria várias classes:

```
class Page(object):
    # ...
    pass

class ResourcePage(Page):
    # ...
    pass

class RichPage(Page):
    # ...
    pass

class MarkdownPage(Page):
    # ...
    pass

# E assim por diante...
```

O usuário do framework pode escrever algo simples com `from framework.page import RichPage`, mas certamente `page.py` será enorme! Uma alternativa é criar vários arquivos:

```
- framework/
  - page/
    - page.py
    - resource.py
    - rich.py
    - markdown.py
    - __init__.py
```

O código ficará muito mais manutenível, né?

## Por quer importar classes no `__init__.py`

### Para facilitar

O código ficará mais manutenível, mas agora nosso pobre usuário deve importar classes assim:

```
from framework.page.rich import RichPage
```

Como [bem disse Phillip J. Eby](http://www.python.org.br/wiki/PythonNaoEJava):

> um programador Python [...] provavelmente vai se irritar ao digitar `Foo.Foo.someMethod` quando deveria ser apenas `Foo.someFunction`.

Então, para ajudar a vida dos nossos usuários, importamos todas as classes no `__init__.py`:

```
from .page import Page
from .resource import ResourPage
from .rich import RichPage
from .markdown import MarkdownPage
```

Agora nosso usuário pode, feliz, apenas invocar:

```
from framework.page import MarkdownPage
```

### Para não quebrar o que já funcionava

Por vezes a principal razão para isso é compatibilidade retrógrada. Nosso framework era pequenino, e todo o código cabia elegantemente no `page.py`. Aos poucos, foi crescendo, e resolvemos separá-lo em arquivos diferentes. Neste caso importar tudo no `__init__.py` é ainda mais importante, pois permite que códigos que usassem a versão antiga continuem rodando na nova.

### Para deixar o namespace limpo

Suponha que nossa classe `MarkdownPage` use uma classe `MarkdownParser`. No caso em que tempos apenas um grande `page.py`, `MarkdownParser` estará disponível pra quem importar `page.py`. Entretanto, isto não é o ideal: `MarkdownParser` é um detalhe de implementação.

Ao colocar a `MarkdownPage` em `markdown.py`, podemos importar apenas o que queremos dela para dentro do `__init__.py`, limpando o *namespace*.

## Vale a pena fora de frameworks?

Bem, isso depende... Em projetos pequenos, quase certamente não. Mas veja só, se seu projeto for grande e tiver uma boa arquitetura, ele será modular, então alguns componentes dele serão, para efeitos gerais, *frameworks* que outras partes do mesmo projeto vão usar, não é verdade? Assim, não estranhe muito se esse padrão aparecer em outros projetos também.

Comment: Excelente explicação. Obrigado.