# Erro: "no module named xxxx"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, importação

Tenho o Python instalado nos meus pcs (Windows 7 e 8) mas não consigo executar nenhum *script* que contenha `import`.

Sempre aparece a mensagem de erro:

> import error: no module named xxxx.

Comment: Qual a versão do Python instalada? Já tentou remover o Python e instalar novamente?

Comment: De certeza que o módulo importado está corretamente instalado ou é um dos módulo que vem por defeito com o python?

Comment: Oi, obrigada pelas respostas!!! Então, eu tenho o 2.7 em um pc e o 3.5 na outro. Ja instalei e re-instalei mil vezes e não funciona :(

Comment: Como eu posso saber se o modulo esta bem instalado, Rui? (se não for muito complicado me explicar)

Comment: @Jana qual o módulo que estás a tentar importar?

Comment: Esse aqui é um dos muitos que não funcionam: import numpy

Comment: Acabei de tentar alguns modulos e eles funcionam:
>>> import os
>>> import shutil
>>> import glob

Comment: @Jana porque esses vêm por defeito com python

Comment: Muito obrigada, Rui!

Comment: @Jana para utilizares o numpy precisas de instalar o pacote primeiro

Comment: Fabio, Rui e jbueno, super obrigada pelas respostas!!! E desculpa ter formulado mal a pergunta. Ja estou tentando resolver a partir das respostas.
Um abração!

Comment: @Jana se o teu sistema operativo for 64 bits se calhar vais ter alguma dificuldade em instalar o numpy para windows, mas creio que é possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando importar módulos que não vêm "embutidos" quando você instala o Python. Isso quer dizer que você terá que instalá-los manualmente.

Você pode fazer isso pelo pip

```
pip install numpy
```

Ou da forma que preferir.

Comment: Essa resposta funciona para muitos dos módulos porém a instalação do `numpy` em Windows é geralmente bem mais chato.

Comment: Eu nunca fiz essa instalação no Windows, mas aparentemente o AP não teve problemas... De qualquer forma, irei procurar sobre isso e tentar melhorar essa resposta (se for algum comportamento imutável).

Comment: Exatamente, sergiopereira. Eu consegui instalar o nltk facilmente, mas o numpy até agora nada... :(

Comment: Para instalar numpy em Windows, o mais fácil é baixar já precompilado [aqui](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) e instalar o arquivo wheel usando algo como `pip install numpy‑1.9.3+mkl‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl`. Tome cuidado para baixar a versão correta para seu Windows (32 vs 64bits) e Python (2.7 vs 3.x)

Comment: Muito atrasada, mas nunca é tarde para agadecer: @sergiopereira, muito obrigada! :)

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava tendo essa mesma resposta de erro. No meu caso, a criação de um arquivo `__init__.py` resolveu o problema do import.
A estrutura ficou assim:

App

- `__init__.py`
- main.py

Test

- `__init__.py`
- test.py

Até onde eu sei esse arquivo init é necessário para inicializar pacotes, ou em POO para inicializar objetos dentro de classes. Então faz sentido que precise criar ele para poder inicializar e importar os módulos dentro de outro arquivo.
Aqui mesmo no SO tem uma resposta que dá mais informações sobre o uso do init:
[Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19263/%c3%89-uma-boa-pr%c3%a1tica-importar-m%c3%b3dulos-no-init-py)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).